# Printing listview using loop prints all rows on the same line C#

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to print a receipt from a window Form using c#, it prints fine with only 1 row in the listview, but when more rows are added, they all print on the same line on the paper

How can I make it print it normally, one row below the other

here is the code I used

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            int ii = 1;
            ii++;

        graphics.DrawString("  " + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text,  new Font("Arial Bold", 11),
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
        }
        Offset = Offset + 20;
```

Comment: what is "ii" variable for?

Comment: I thought using ii for subitems, but them it didn't work out alright so I removed it but forgot to remove this line, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the line `Offset = Offset + 20` within the `for` loop instead of after the closing bracket. Currently, your loop is printing everything, and after it finishes you are then incrementing `Offset`.

It may also be better to use `Offset += 20` to make it more readable.

Also, as someone else has advised you use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop, I disagree. A `for` loop in general requires less memory than a `foreach` loop and in this case, a `for` loop would be more suitable.

Please [see here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach) for information.

**EDIT:**
Let me rescind my statement about `for` vs `foreach` **in this particular case**. Due to your loop accessing the array element several times during each iteration, in this example a `foreach` loop would be faster than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a much more better approach to iterate through your `ListBox` control using a `foreach` loop since you are going through all the items:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
        graphics.DrawString("  " + item.SubItems[0].Text + item.SubItems[1].Text + item.SubItems[2].Text + item.SubItems[3].Text,  new Font("Arial Bold", 11),
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);

        Offset = Offset + 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate, you rock

Comment: You are welcome. Dont forget to upvote those answers that helped you :)